# Using SSMTP with PHPMailer

Tags: php, ssmtp

I'm not sure if this need to be posted here or on StackOverflow because I'm not sure if the problem is with PHPMailer or SSMTP.

I'm having some trouble sending emails using PHPMailer and SSMTP.

I have configured SSMTP to use an external server to send emails. The authentication is successful and emails are sent to my inbox. The problem is that the 'From' is "World Wide Web Owner" (but the email address is ok) and the email body is empty.

The "FromLineOverride" is set to "YES" in my ssmtp.conf file.
I have also set the sendmail_path to /usr/local/sbin/ssmtp -t in my php.ini file.
My script calls PHPMailer in the default way (mail). I have also tried setting it up to Sendmail, but no success.
My script also sets the path to ssmtp in PHPMailer (PHPMailer::$Sendmail) with "-t"

I have searched for a couple hours, but none of my search really helped me.

Is there something?